# Applescript: how can I perform an action on all Finder windows, only in current desktop?

Tags: applescript

On Mountain Lion, I'm trying to create an AppleScript app to resize all Finder windows in the current Desktop (aka space).

I'd like to simply navigate to the space in question, click an app, and have it resize all open Finder windows -- in that space only -- to a fixed size.

I've got a script to do what I need, but it operates on every Finder window, across ALL spaces. **How can I limit it to the current space?** Thank you.

```
tell application "Finder"
set theFolders to folder of every window
set theBounds to {10, 10, 310, 310}

repeat with aFolder in theFolders
    tell container window of aFolder
        set toolbar visible to false
            set bounds to theBounds
    end tell
end repeat
end tell
```

This code stacks windows on top of one another. That's not a problem. I know how to cascade if I want, but I currently prefer to manually position them using "divvy".

I'm running this resize code to work around a Mountain Lion "feature" that limits minimum Finder window widths, and interaction with the side panel toolbar. This code does what I want, just on too many windows.